What is the max height my gambrel roof truss will sit at?
I'm building a 10x12 gambrel style shed in my back yard and my max shed height is regulated. I've found a good plan to use, but it doesn't show the truss height and i need it to figure my total shed height. For you math wizards, what would be the height based on the shown measurements? If you could explain your work it'd be appreciated.
Thanks

The easiest way is to measure the ratio of the height to width of that image on your monitor, and then multiply by 10'.  The ratio I get is 5.4/11.2 ~ 0.48.  10' X 0.48 = 4.8' or about 4' 9.5".  I'm a math guy, but I'd rather not spend the time to do geometry class to solve the problem, unless you are within inches of some threshold.  This is all assuming the drawing is actually dimensionally accurate.

The 10 foot width is drawn is neither inside nor outside dimension.  The two bottom corners are labelled 22.5 which isn't possible if the three roof angles are all 22.5.  The h??? Height is drawn from somewhere above the floor.  If you create a correctly labelled diagram this could be answered in Math SE or Wolfram or any math engine.  It's just solving two triangles.  Also, in math circles you don't label angles by their rotation, you label the interior angles of the shape. I suggest you do that for the three roof angles ... 157.5.

If the image is to scale, the approximate height is fifty-six and a half inches in the ??? marked area. I used a screen capture, then a screen calipers and calibrated to match the 50.5" measurements on the rafters. Cheating, but I didn't want to do the math either.
I used another similar method and arrived at fifty-seven and a half inches.
If the image is not to scale, disregard this answer.

You've presented a math challenge, but most carpenters won't take the trigonometric approach. See the Math Stack for that. My approach would be to lay it out on the garage floor or driveway.
Snap a straight line with impermanent chalk to represent the baseline. Mark a zero point and a 10 ft point.
Now take some lumber and set the two initial angles from those points using an adjustable square. Take into consideration the actual rafter position on the shed walls. Measure and mark up the slope from the baseline 50½" and set two more.
Now check everything by measuring the effective rafter lengths for each segment. Fudge things until they match, then re-check the angles. Also measure from the initial zero and 10 ft. marks to the peak on each side. Those should match.
Find a happy compromise and trace it before it gets bumped. Measure the height. The benefit to this approach is that forgetting to carry a one doesn't mean your shed violates city ordinance when you're done building it.
